# How to extract an Indian mobile number from an excel worksheet?

Tags: excel

If the mobile number has 10 digits only and starts with either 9 or 8 or 7,

how can I extract those numbers from excel worksheet ?

Comment: Thank you for the question. Yes, the numbers could be anywhere in the text i.e. in any row or any column. By extract, i meant any means to view/copy such number strings alone.

Comment: If you want to help us to solve your problem please provide some sample data and expected result. The problem might be clear to you but I don't understand what is it and what are you trying to achieve. Otherwise you are likely to get downvotes instead of answers.

Comment: I have got addresses of people in a single column. e.g. some person, some house, some street, some building, mob: 9874565414, but i want to get the 10 digit number only.

Answer (score 0):

is the data separated by and spaces or characters : ; etc?

You may be better in that case using text to columns if the data is in some kind of order, using spaces as delimiter - and if you still have problems getting all the numbers in the same column its either manual data manipulation or VBA etc to iterate over the whole set.